# How to map the Flux result to another object type with ReactiveMongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-jpa, aggregation-framework, reactive-programming

The find API in java Spring @Repository class wants to return a `Flux<AggregatedObject>`, but the getReactiveMongoTemplate().find() returns a Document of different type. What could be the best way to convert the resultant Flux to AggregatedObject type?

```
public Flux<AggregatedObject> find() {
    Criteria filterCriteria = getFilterCriteria();
    Query query = new BasicQuery(filterCriteria.getCriteriaObject());
    Flux flux = getReactiveMongoTemplate().find(query, Document.class, collectionName);
    // how to convert Document to AggregatedObject and return?
}
```

Comment: Which field are you doing Aggregation ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add your `AggregatedObject` as [parametrized type](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/ReactiveMongoTemplate.html#find-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-):

```
public Flux<AggregatedObject> find() {
    Criteria filterCriteria = getFilterCriteria();
    Query query = new Query(filterCriteria);
    return getReactiveMongoTemplate().find(query, AggregatedObject.class, collectionName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can do it like this;

```
flux.map(d -> reactiveMongoTemplate.getConverter()
                .read(AggregatedObject.class, d.get("value", Document.class)))
```